# Core Data - Get objectIDs of to-many relationship without firing a fault

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data

I have an entity with a to-many relationship. After I fetch a subset of objects from my entity, I would like to get the ManagedObjectIDs of the relationship objects - without firing a fault. Is this possible? My understanding from the documentation is that calling objectID on a fault does not cause it to fire, but when I try the following line, a fault is fired for each object's relationship nonetheless:

```
[word.articles valueForKeyPath:@"objectID"];
```

I have also tried the following, with the same result:

```
[word valueForKeyPath:@"articles.objectID"];
```

I have now also tried the following, but unfortunately article faults still fire:

```
for (Article *article in word.articles) {

   [articleIDs addObject:article.objectID];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated please!

Comment: No error occurs - all that happens is that a fault is fired, which means a trip to the store, and a significant increase in processing time

Answer (score 4):

This was made possible in iOS 8.3

```
/* returns an array of objectIDs for the contents of a relationship. 
   to-one relationships will return an NSArray with a single 
   NSManagedObjectID.  Optional relationships may return an empty 
   NSArray. 
   The objectIDs will be returned in an NSArray regardless of the type 
   of the relationship.  */
- (NSArray<NSManagedObjectID *> *)objectIDsForRelationshipNamed:(NSString *)key NS_AVAILABLE(10_11,8_3);
```

It does one trip to the store to get all the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create an NSFetchRequest for the Articles entity using a predicate like this (where 'word' is a word managed object):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY words == %@)", word];
```

Set resultType = NSManagedObjectIDResultType as Ashley says in his answer.

The fetch request will then return a collection of Article ObjectIDs for articles containing the specified word.

OR: If you want to look up by the text of the word rather than fetching it as a managed object first then use a predicate like this. (where 'wordText' is an NSString and assuming - 'text' is a field of the Word entity)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY words.text == %@)", wordText];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option as it would require all words for all articles to be matched to the words being sought. The database contains thousands of articles and each article contains hundreds of words.

Comment: I am assuming that 'Run Loop' is trying to find all articles that contain a given word. When a new article is added each word in the article is added as a 'Word' entity and the relationships are set up. This is a fairly typical thing to do with a database. If this is not the case then Run Loop needs to explain in greater detail what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Robin - That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @RunLoop Good. Well, have I answered your question then?

Comment: No, but in your comment you affirmed my comment about why your answer would not be an option.

Comment: I'm really confused now. CastToInteger said that it wouldn't be an option not you. I was asking you to clarify what you were trying to do. If you want to index each article by the words it contains then you will need to keep each unique (and non trivial) word as a Word entity and set up relationships to each article. If you don't want to do that then you will need to do a full text search of each article every time you want to look up which articles contain a given word.

Comment: Sorry meant to say CastToInteger's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to use an NSFetchRequest, for entity Articles, and setting

```
request.resultType = NSManagedObjectIDResultType
```

If the problem is **multiple** faults firing (so multiple SQL requests), how about a fetch request to fetch **all** your required Articles initially, meaning only a single SQL request is made?

Comment: The problem is I would not know what articles to include in the request - to know that I would have to query word.articles, which would fire a fault and brings us back to my question as explained above

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to perform prefetching so that your relationship objects are fetched during your initial fetch and therefore will not cause faults later.

Look into the `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` property in the `NSFetchRequest` class. Here is an example where the `request` is returning an array of `Word` objects that contain an `articles` property:

```
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[@"articles"]];
```